# Continuously scroll an element to bottom and back to top of a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I am trying to automatically `.animate` the `.scrollTop` of a `<div>` **contained within another `<div>`**. I have done this so I could hide the *scroll-bar* thus only display the text. Therefore, I know how to scroll that particular `<div>` with **JQuery** as such:

```
$("#div").animate({ scrollTop: "+=5" }, 200);
```

But what I am trying to do is to **continuously** `.animate` the content until it reaches the bottom of that particular `<div>` and then animates back to the top of the `<div>` ( `.scrollTop: '0px'`). THere is where I am struggling with.

- I am currently pulling content into a `<div>` which the result of a
  query. Therefore, I do not know the full length of the content that
  will be placed of that `<div>`.
- The `<div>` that contains the content is within another `<div>` and I don't think the method to detect the bottom of the  `<div>` works correctly (or perhaps I am doing something wrong).

  ```
  var div = $(this);
  if (div[0].scrollHeight - div.scrollTop() == div.height())
  ```

I was wondering if someone can give me a hand with this. Since I have not seen a particular approach like this in this forum or by Googleing for it.

So pretty much what I have is this:

```
if ($('#resultProviders').scrollTop() >= $('#resultProviders').innerHeight()) {
    $('#resultProviders').animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 800);
} else {
$('#resultProviders').animate({scrollTop: '+=30px'}, 500);
};
```

I have also provided a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trinkermedia/ebhydbp3/5/) for this.

https://jsfiddle.net/trinkermedia/ebhydbp3/5/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a scroll function with a parameter, like shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebhydbp3/6/).

```
function _scroll(goDown) {
    goDown = goDown == undefined ? true: goDown;
    var frame = $('#resultProviders'),
        content = $('#resultProviders ul'),
        scrollTo;
    if (goDown) {
        scrollTo = content.outerHeight() - frame.outerHeight();
    } else {
        scrollTo = 0
    }
    frame.animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        complete: function() {_scroll(!goDown)}
    });
}
```

Comment: It will work always as long as there is a frame with a fixed with (#resultProviders) and a content-container, that has the full height of the content in it.

Answer (score 0):

Things are so simple with **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**, here is your fiddle: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebhydbp3/9/)**.

***JavaScript:***

```
TweenMax.to('#resultProviders', 2, { scrollTo: { y: 'max' }, repeat: -1, yoyo: true, ease: Power2.easeInOut });
```

Apologies if this wasn't you were looking for or if you were not interested in solutions utilising anything else other than jQuery.